# how to write a query to get the employee ID, first_name, last_name, salary in ascending order of salary(in Employees table) in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to retrieve employee id, first & last name, salary in ascending order of salary using find().

[This is the structure of Employees.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0uWu.gif)

Comment: I have added two documents in the collection. I want to get the results from both the documents. I tried my best but got results from only one document. Could anyone come up with a solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query worked for me:

```
db.Employees.find({},{"last_name":1,"first_name":1,"employee_id":1,"salary":1}).sort({"salary":1}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.employees.find({EMPLOYEE_ID: employeeId}, {FIRST_NAME: 1, LAST_NAME: 1, SALARY: 1}).sort({ SALARY: 1})
```

Comment: I tried to execute this query but nothing is getting displayed on the screen. Could you please tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: @Bharath This returns cursor. If you want to use the result, you should put .toArray() behind sort()

Comment: It is just displaying empty brackets. My employee ids are 456 and 457. I used 457. But it just displyas empty brackets. what could be the problem

Comment: @Bharath Then, just do db.employees.find({EMPLOY_ID: employeeId}).toArray(). What is the result?

Comment: Just a pair of empty brackets. That's it. I did like this. db.employees.find({employee_id:456}).toArray().

Comment: @Bharath You should have told me that you need to find all documents from collection... Anyway, congratulation!